# Navigate to nuxt error page via client side?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vue-router

When I deploy a universal app with nuxt, I'm noticing client-side $axios requests that throw an exception are merely returning the error code to the console. Is there a way to have nuxt redirect to the error.vue we specify in the layouts folder? I only seem to be able to get to this page by calling the `context.error` method on the server side.

i've been approaching it as below:

```js
async submit (evt) {
  try {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get(`some/url`)
    ...
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e) // assume, for the sake of argument, that the error is: { 'statusCode': 403, 'message': 'Forbidden' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `catch` you can redirect user to error page by

```
    return this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'err message' })
```

and in your `error.vue` page you can access it with `error` prop like:

```
<h1>{{ error.statusCode }}</h1>
<h2>{{ error.message }} </h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have access to the same error method on the client-side via `$nuxt` utility. Works exactly the same, so you can throw an error for example like this:

`$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404 })`